# How do I Localize a Class Display Name

Tags: c#, localization, data-annotations

How do I localize using resource files the DisplayName for the class.
The Display Attribute does not work on classes and the DisplayName Attribute does not support localization.

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ServiceType.ServiceTypeMetadata))]
// Compile Error: Attribute 'Display' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, param' declarations.
// [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.DisplayNames), Name = "ServiceType")] 
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Service Type")]
public partial class ServiceType : ILookupEntity<EdmBilingualStringVarCharSingleLine>, ISelectListEntity, IUpdateableEntity
{
    #region Metadata
    internal sealed class ServiceTypeMetadata
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.DisplayNames), Name = "InactiveDate")]
        public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.DisplayNames), Name = "ModifiedBy")]
        [Required]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.DisplayNames), Name = "ModifiedDate")]
        [Required]
        public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    }
    #endregion

    // ... the rest of the class ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create your own Display Name attribute. The following worked for me and could be made more generic by passing the Resource file name which in my case I simply hardcoded.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Resources;


namespace SCC.Case.Entities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a class attribute that lets you specify the localizable string for the entity class
    /// </summary>
    class DisplayNameForClassAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("SCC.Case.Entities.DisplayNames", typeof(DisplayNameForClassAttribute).Assembly);
                return resourceManager.GetString(this.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```